# Memory leakage in php with three for loops

Tags: php, memory, memory-leaks, memory-management

My script is a spider that checks if a page is a "links page" or is a "information page".
if the page is a "links page" then it continue in a recursive manner (or a tree if you will)
until it finds the "information page".

I tried to make the script recursive and it was easy but i kept getting the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 39 bytes) in /srv/www/loko/simple_html_dom.php on line 1316

I was told i would have to use the **for loop method** because no matter if i use the unset() function the script won't free memory and i only have three levels i need to loop through so it makes sense. But after i changed the script the error occurs again, **but maybe i can free
memory now?**

Something needs to die here, please help me destruct someone!

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
require("simple_html_dom.php");
$thelink = "http://www.somelink.com";
$html1 = file_get_html($thelink);
$ret1 = $html1->find('#idTabResults2');

// first inception level, we know page has only links
if (!$ret1){
    $es1 = $html1->find('table.litab a');
    //unset($html1);
    $countlinks1 = 0;
    foreach ($es1 as $aa1) {
        $links1[$countlinks1] = $aa1->href;
        $countlinks1++;
    }
    //unset($es1);

    //for every link in array do the same
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countlinks1; $i++) {
        $html2 = file_get_html($links1[$i]);
        $ret2 = $html2->find('#idTabResults2');
        // if got information then send to DB
        if ($ret2){
            pullInfo($html2);
            //unset($html2);
        } else {
        // continue inception
            $es2 = $html2->find('table.litab a');
            $html2 = null;

            $countlinks2 = 0;
            foreach ($es2 as $aa2) {
            $links2[$countlinks2] = $aa2->href;
            $countlinks2++;
            }
            //unset($es2);

            for ($j = 0; $j < $countlinks2; $j++) {
                $html3 = file_get_html($links2[$j]);
                $ret3 = $html3->find('#idTabResults2');
                // if got information then send to DB       
                if ($ret3){
                    pullInfo($html3);

                } else {
                // inception level three
                    $es3 = $html3->find('table.litab a');
                    $html3 = null;
                    $countlinks3 = 0;
                    foreach ($es3 as $aa3) {
                        $links3[$countlinks3] = $aa3->href;
                        $countlinks3++;
                    }
                    for ($k = 0; $k < $countlinks3; $k++) {
                        echo memory_get_usage() ;
                        echo "\n";
                        $html4 = file_get_html($links3[$k]);
                        $ret4 = $html4->find('#idTabResults2');
                        // if got information then send to DB       
                        if ($ret4){
                            pullInfo($html4);

                        }
                        unset($html4);                  
                    }
                    unset($html3);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}



function pullInfo($html)
{

$tds = $html->find('td');
$count =0; 
foreach ($tds as $td) {
  $count++;
  if ($count==1){
    $name = html_entity_decode($td->innertext);
   }
  if ($count==2){
        $address = addslashes(html_entity_decode($td->innertext));
   }
  if ($count==3){
    $number = addslashes(preg_replace('/(\d+) - (\d+)/i', '$2$1', $td->innertext));
   }

}
unset($tds, $td);

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($number);
$inAlready=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE phone=$number");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($inAlready))
            $output[]=$e;
    if (json_encode($output) != "null"){ 
        //print(json_encode($output));
    } else {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (name, area, phone)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$number')");
}
}
```

And here is a picture of the growth in memory size:
[image]

Comment: require("simple_html_dom.php"); could it be happening here?

Comment: @NSjonas what do you mean? and RPM i'm running it in bash

Comment: By the way, your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Note that you can replace this `$data1 = file_get_contents($thelink);
$html1 = str_get_html($data1);` with `$html1 = file_get_html($thelink);`. This avoids keeping multiple representations of each document in memory.

Comment: You might also want to free each of the three documents when you're done using them.

Comment: @MichaelMior how do i do that?

Comment: You can use `unset($html1);` when you're done with `$html1`.

Comment: implemented.. no change though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code a little bit to free as much memory as I see could be freed.
I've added a comment above each modification. The added comments start with "#" so you could find them easier.
This is not related to this question, but worth mentioning that your database insertion code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
<?php
require("simple_html_dom.php");
$thelink = "http://www.somelink.co.uk";

# do not keep raw contents of the file on memory
#$data1 = file_get_contents($thelink);
#$html1 = str_get_html($data1);
$html1 = str_get_html(file_get_contents($thelink));

$ret1 = $html1->find('#idResults2');

// first inception level, we know page has only links
if (!$ret1){
    $es1 = $html1->find('table.litab a');

    # free $html1, not used anymore
    unset($html1);

    $countlinks1 = 0;
    foreach ($es1 as $aa1) {
        $links1[$countlinks1] = $aa1->href;
        $countlinks1++;
        // echo (addslashes($aa->href));
    }

    # free memroy used by the $es1 value, not used anymore
    unset($es1);

    //for every link in array do the same

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $countlinks1; $i++) {
        # do not keep raw contents of the file on memory
        #$data2 = file_get_contents($links1[$i]);
        #$html2 = str_get_html($data2);
        $html2 = str_get_html(file_get_contents($links1[$i]));

        $ret2 = $html2->find('#idResults2');

        // if got information then send to DB
        if ($ret2){
            pullInfo($html2);
        } else {
        // continue inception

            $es2 = $html2->find('table.litab a');

            # free memory used by $html2, not used anymore.
            # we would unset it at the end of the loop.
            $html2 = null;

            $countlinks2 = 0;
            foreach ($es2 as $aa2) {
                $links2[$countlinks2] = $aa2->href;
                $countlinks2++;
            }

            # free memory used by $es2
            unest($es2);

            for ($j = 0; $j <= $countlinks2; $j++) {
                # do not keep raw contents of the file on memory
                #$data3 = file_get_contents($links2[$j]);
                #$html3 = str_get_html($data3);
                $html3 = str_get_html(file_get_contents($links2[$j]));
                $ret3 = $html3->find('#idResults2');
                // if got information then send to DB   
                if ($ret3){
                    pullInfo($html3);
                }

                # free memory used by $html3 or on last iteration the memeory would net get free
                unset($html3);
            }
        }

        # free memory used by $html2 or on last iteration the memeory would net get free
        unset($html2);
    }
}



function pullInfo($html)
{
    $tds = $html->find('td');
    $count =0; 
    foreach ($tds as $td) {
      $count++;
      if ($count==1){
        $name = addslashes($td->innertext);
       }
      if ($count==2){
            $address = addslashes($td->innertext);
       }
      if ($count==3){
        $number = addslashes(preg_replace('/(\d+) - (\d+)/i', '$2$1', $td->innertext));
       }

    }

    # check for available data:
    if ($count) {
        # free $tds and $td
        unset($tds, $td);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO people (name, area, phone)
        VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$number')");
    }

}
```

**Update:**

You could trace your memory usage to see how much memory is being used in each section of your code. this could be done by using the memory_get_usage() calls, and saving the result to some file. like placing this below code in the end of each of your loops, or before creating objects, calling heavy methods:

```
file_put_contents('memory.log', 'memory used in line ' . __LINE__ . ' is: ' . memory_get_usage() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

So you could trace the memory usage of each part of your code.

In the end remember all this tracing and optimization might not be enough, since your application might really need more memory than 32 MB. I'v developed a system that analyzes several data sources and detects spammers, and then blocks their SMTP connections and since sometimes the number of connected users are over 30000, after a lot of code optimization, I had to increase the PHP memory limit to 768 MB on the server, Which is not a common thing to do.

Comment: still failed at the same spot :/ ohh

Comment: fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 39 bytes) in /srv/www/loko/simple_html_dom.php on line 1288

Comment: @Tom: what about the simple_html_dom.php file? is it a well written library? is there any other library you could use to help you? I suggest you place some memory_get_usage() calls in your script and store them in some file to debug and find where the memory usage jumps up. That is where you should optimize the code. In the end you might need to change your application structure to avoid nested loops.

Comment: It's a well known library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ i'm trying to use memory_get_usage(). i revised my code.

Comment: @Tom: Updated the answer describing more about tracing memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

If your operation requires memory and your server has more memory available, you can call `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` or something similar (depending your memory requirement) to increase the amount of memory available to the script.

This does not mean you should not optimise and refactor your code :-) this is just one part.

Comment: The memory leakage grows exponentially so increasing the memory this way will never help :/ thanks for the advice i learned something else on the way :)

Comment: It's uncontrolled usage rather than a leakage I think - you are telling the script to fetch all links and generate HTML objects on each of them and do the same again. So, you should refactor and put this code inside a function you can call and unset the object once you are done with it. Unset will free memory, albeit not immediately.

Comment: i added ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); it ran for another minute or so but failed when memory reached to 256MB. it's only 1/9 of the way it has to go. This is insane.. 256MB for storing links (strings)? what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the clear method such as:
$html4->clear(); a simple_html_dom method to clear memory When you are finished with the DOM element.
If you want to learn more, enter [this website](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-simple-html-dom-parser-allowed-memory-exhausted/).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's turn this into a truly recursive function, should make it easier to modify the whole chain of events that way:

```
function findInfo($thelink)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($thelink);  //Might want to make sure that it's a valid link, i.e. that file get contents actually returned stuff, before trying to run further with it.
    $html = str_get_html($data);

    unset($data);  //Finished using it, no reason to keep it around.

    $ret = $html->find('#idResults2');

    if($ret)
    {
         pullInfo($html);
         return true;    //Should stop once it finds it right?
    }
    else
    {
         $es = $html->find('table.litab a');  //Might want a little error checking here to make sure it actually found links.

         unset($html); //Finished using it, no reason to keep it around

         $countlinks = 0;

         foreach($es as $aa)
         {
              $links[$countlinks] = $aa->href;
              $countlinks++;
         }

         unset($es);  //Finished using it, no reason to keep it around.

         for($i = 0; $i <= $countlinks; $i++)
         {
              $result = findInfo($links[$i]);

              if($result === true)
              {
                  return true;  //To break out of above recursive functions if lower functions return true
              }
              else
              {
                  unset($links[$i]); //Finished using it, no reason to keep it around.
                  continue;
              }
         }     
    }
    return false;  //Will return false if all else failed, should hit a return true before this point if it successfully finds an info page.
}
```

See if that helps at all with the cleanups.  Probably still run out of memory, but you shouldn't be holding onto the full html of each webpage scanned and what not with this.

Oh, and if you only want it to go only so deep, change the function declaration to something like:

```
function findInfo($thelink, $depth = 1, $maxdepth = 3)
```

Then when calling the function within the function, call it like so:

```
findInfo($html, $depth + 1, $maxdepth); //you include maxdepth so you can override it in the initial function call, like findInfo($thelink,,4)
```

and then do a check on depth vs. maxdepth at the start of the function and have it `return false` if depth is `>` than maxdepth.

Comment: wow what an effort on your behalf Phonix! i will try this also and see what goes

Comment: @Tom Since it seems to be failing when doing some function in the included library, the next thing I'd do is pin it down to where it is failing exactly.  Add console or log output just before using each function from the library like `str_get_html` and `->find`.  Also possible that it's failing in `pullInfo`, maybe there are so many tds on the page that it takes up all the memory trying to find them all.  Never know.

Answer (score -1):

If memory usage is your primary concern, you may want to consider using a SAX-based parser. Coding using a SAX parser can be a bit more complicated, but it's not necessary to keep the entire document in memory.

Comment: I'll take a look into it Michael, for now i'm implementing your suggestion above to see if it helped.